# Is it OK to unaccept an answer after weeks?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, etiquette, unaccepted-answer

I happened to ask [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23627317/filter-records-by-year-and-month-where-year-and-month-are-columns-in-the-table) a couple of weeks ago, to which I received prompt responses that worked for me.

However, I just figured out that there is a bug with the answer.

Although the answer did work for me initially and I did accept/upvote the answer, is it OK to downvote and unaccept it after a period of inactivity even though this stems from a lack of rigorous testing on my part?

Comment: Of course it is acceptable, especially if you leave a comment explaining the bug you discovered. Consider how it will benefit future readers of the question.

Comment: It's okay, but I would probably give the answerer a chance to fix the answer before DVing or unaccepting.

Comment: Unaccept, edit then accept?

Comment: You asked a question (which doesn't contain any attempted sql, so I would say it's a _poor_ question), you got answers doing what you ask and then a week or so later you find new information and want to unaccept (fine) and downvote (IMO absolutely not fine. You'd also need the answer to be edited to do that if you'd already upvoted it)? Downvotes should be reserved for _unhelpful_ answers, an answer you previously accepted surely was helpful; Gordon's answer appears to address the failing you've pointed out in comments.

Comment: @DavidRobinson ah .. so it work this way? in fact answere is just having his time to answer question if u downvote he will not answer anymore this is just crap! it will only benefit gremlins

Comment: If there is a better answer to the question, you can and should accept THAT one over the currently accepted answer.

Removing an upvote from a response you feel is not sufficient, I'm okay with.  However, if it sufficiently and helpfully answers the question, as it stands...then no.  Edit your question then remove the upvote.

Downvoting a response is far less acceptable.  That should be reserved for reponses of low-quality.

Comment: I over-stated my case: the change required is not as trivial as my earlier comment suggested, but it is also far from impossible.  I've created a CW answer with the original answer, suggested upgrades to the original answer, and some commentary on the code.  Are there any DBMS where `x BETWEEN y AND z` is not treated as `x >= y AND x <= z` (e.g. that treat it as `x >= MIN(y, z) AND z <= MAX(y, z)`)?

Comment: @Serendipity: unless comments have been deleted on those answers, I would be intrigued as to why you did not interact with people who you believed were initially helpful.

Comment: @halfer: I did. The original answer has been deleted.

Comment: Well, okay, but there are three other answers still there, with no comments on them - and Jonathan clearly put substantial time and thought into his answer. Whilst we don't want lengthy chat in comments, I think some acknowledgement of effort is a good thing, as with any community.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The acceptance check mark is completely within your power as the asker of the question.

If you realise a better answer has appeared you can move the acceptance to that answer.

If you realise that the currently accepted answer doesn't actually help you then you can remove the acceptance altogether.

However, if the mistake is apparently fixable then you should either edit it yourself - if you can - or leave a comment for the answerer for them to fix it. In this case I'd be extremely reluctant to down-vote - after all the answer *was* helpful - it got you out of your initial hole.

Comment: It's worth mentioning vote locking - one would be unable to downvote it after upvoting earlier unless it's edited.

Comment: @Dukeling - indeed - though I deliberately didn't address whether the answer had been voted on.

Comment: Yes, you'll notice that they is vote locking, but no "accepted locking". This is because whether a question is accepted can depend on *other answers* as well, i.e. a better one comes along, whereas a vote (should) depend on the answer itself.

Comment: I realize I shouldn't have down-voted the answer. It did work (for as long as it worked).

Answer (score 17):

It is *essential* to unaccept and downvote a bad answer.  This is how SO works, it is only useful as a resource to other programmers when the correct answer is clearly visible as the correct one.  And that works by the number of votes an answer gets and whether it was found to be correct by the questioner.  So leaving it on top of the list of answers and marked with the green check mark doesn't help anybody.

No reason to let anybody else suffer through the same bug when they google that answer.

Comment: In general, I agree.  In this case, it wasn't a bad answer; it is simply that it wasn't a perfect answer, but it was easily fixable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Maybe you could post a fixed answer (as community wiki) and the questioner could then accept it. Don't understand why the answer had to be deleted.

Comment: @Trilarion: I have created a CW answer for the question.  It was a little less trivial than I thought (and the SQL is untested), but it was certainly doable.