# When is it okay to remove acceptance of an answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, unaccepted-answer

Recently I posted an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519026/how-to-create-this-special-toggle-sort-of-button-android/28519143?noredirect=1#comment45355451_28519143). After some clarification in the comments, it was ticked as accepted and up voted. After a little while, both the acceptance and the up vote was removed, followed by a comment that presented a problem that was not originally stated in the question.

To me it came on as rude, I could understand if the author would un-tick the answer but to remove the up vote was a bit dramatic.

When it it okay to remove the acceptance of an answer? Was it okay in my case?

Comment: I would say whenever OP feels like doing so.

Comment: OPs have all control of their acceptance of a question. There is no way this can be "not okay". The decision is completely in the hands of the OP, so it's up to him to accept what he wants. And I see both an up and a downvote on the answer. You're sure the upvote was cancelled, not simply that you got downvoted to bring you back at 0?

Comment: I did not think of that @Patrice. I have not yet reached 1000 rep, so I can not see the vote count yet :-)

Comment: @Marcus fair enough ^^ But yeah, in a side note, what you're describing is a "chameleon question". Look at this article for what to do with them http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions :)

Comment: Thanks for the the reference link @Patrice, I'll have a look. Also, it seems that I need to have another look on the stack overflow meta site help forum, since my questions is getting heavily down voted.

Comment: Also related: [Is it OK to unaccept an answer after weeks?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256585/is-it-ok-to-unaccept-an-answer-after-weeks)

Comment: @Marcus don't take downvotes here to heart. They don't change your rep anyway, and sometimes they are simply used as a way to disagree. Since here it can be seen as you "ranting", a lot of people will downvote simply because of that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Patrice. I will keep it in mind in the future :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no rule that coerces when the OP can remove the acceptance mark. There's no flag to be raised when that happens and there is no appeal to be made to the mods. So the OP can revoke acceptance for whatever reason the OP has.

There are situation where I think most people would agree that the mark should be removed from an answer:

1. The OP later finds that the accepted answer was not helpful after all. Sometimes what appears to be a valid answer is revealed to be faulty only after trying to use it. And, no, the OP does not have to give a reason.
2. The answer was helpful, but someone posted an answer that was even *more* helpful. There's only one mark, and no rule that it should be awarded to the earliest helpful answer.

At the same time, irrespective of the fact that the OP is always *allowed* to remove the mark, there's a social aspect to this. So yeah, there are times when the OP's use of the mark can seem ungrateful, but there is no recourse and, for the sake of your own well-being, it is better to move on.

Comment: If I would apply this answer to my specific case; it would be, by the standards or policy of this community, fine for the author to remove the acceptance mark from my answer, at any time he/she chooses. However, when viewing this from a bit wider, social perspective it could be deemed as wrong/unfitting/not appropriate. Is this observation correct?

Comment: Yes, that's it!