# What to do if the guy who asked the question use your answer to create another one?

Tags: discussion

I have some troubles with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435683/deserialize-with-gson-and-null-values/33435722#33435722).

To sum up this guy asked a question, I answered (+2 and mark as answered). But today this guy create his own one and mark it.

> With the code from Maloubobola I got a answer...

This seems to be

- a duplicate
- not fair
- abusive

Should I do something ? If yes what can I do ?

This is not a major problem since this is about gain/lose 15 points but I find that disrespectful to the job I did

Comment: I mean honestly, It's a pretty rude thing to do, but I don't think there can be much done about it, since the person who asked chooses whose answer to accept (Including his own).

Comment: @gnat: Nope, that's unrelated to this issue

Comment: @gnat ,no it's not a duplicate, the guy didn't enhance the answer or improve it, he simply copied part of the answer, and answered his own question, then accepted his own answer.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286076/839601

Comment: But OP says "After some testing **I have some little fixes to your code**" ... (BTW not very nice to see the Meta effect downvoting a (most likely) correct answer.)

Comment: But the `little fixes` were already in his comment (and I upvoted this comment because it was correct and usefull. Now the fixes are mix with the answer). His answer is correct, no doubt with that.

Comment: *But the little fixes were already in his comment* - Corrections to an answer belong in an answer, not in comments which can be deleted at any time.

Comment: Ok, so I was wrong. Thanks for your comments / answers.

Comment: @Cerbrus as far as I can tell, it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I do something ?

No. You should not. The OP provided an answer that worked for them. They acknowledged that your answer was helpful too. Good job.

> This seems to be ... a duplicate

The answer provided by the OP is not a duplicate. Their answer provides a single line of code. This line of code does not appear in your answer (or any of your revisions to your answer) at all. They've provided an answer that works for them based on the answer you provided. That does not make it a duplicate. Their answer isn't as comprehensive as yours, but that doesn't make it a duplicate.

> This seems to be ... not fair

Oh? Do all of your questions in the world get answered by other people and you use their answers exactly as provided? The OP, in this case, received an answer that pointed them in the correct direction to investigate. They found an answer and took a few minutes to document that it worked for them.

If anything is unfair, it is this meta post that brought downvotes to an answer that worked for the OP.

> This seems to be ... abusive

It is not. Full stop. A user is allowed to answer their own question. A user is allowed to use the the work of others to come up with an answer (as long as they cite the work, which this user did). A user is allowed to change the accepted answer at any time for any reason, as long as they aren't performing any voting fraud on this site.

> I find that disrespectful to the job I did

I find it disrespectful that you assume a user, who is using different code than you but acknowledges your help in their answer, is to not intelligent enough to modify your answer to work for them and solve their problem.

Comment: `Should I do something ? No`. So I did nothing. I asked for an advice, I get one. Thank for your detailed answer.