# What can or should I do about an accepted answer that becomes unaccepted?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, unaccepted-answer

In November, I wrote an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33616049/inconsistent-bar-widths-when-month-scaling-in-ggplot/33619670#33619670) and it was accepted. It's probably not the best post on SO, but IMHO it is good enough to keep because others might stumble upon this same bug/feature.

Two months later, the OP unaccepted the answer. I have read that an OP can [unaccept an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256585/is-it-ok-to-unaccept-an-answer-after-weeks). However, in this case there was neither an explanation nor was another answer accepted (there is only one). I thought the unacceptance was a pity, because it's a good answer; unaccepted answers will be found and used less frequently, will show up differently in stats, etc. And of course, losing rep always feels like something is taken from you :-(.

I have already tried to ask the OP for a reason; maybe I can improve something, but there has been no response (for 2 weeks). What else can/should I do?

Comment: _"What else can/should I do?"_ Move on.

Comment: Yeah, there is nothing to be done. It happens to all of us occasionally. Just shrug it off

Comment: The comment you left on your answer won't notify the OP. Commend on the question if you want that. (Or just let it go.)

Comment: @Mat I have used an '@' to notify him. Isn't that enough?

Comment: No, that only works for people who have already commented (or edited) on the post itself (the Q or A).

Comment: Something fishy is going on, the question was upvoted at the exact same time your answer was unaccepted.  Somebody is not using socks to keep his feet warm.  You can flag a moderator.

Comment: Perhaps the OP is attempting to unaccept the answer and attempt to delete the question.

Comment: "Perhaps the OP is attempting to unaccept the answer and attempt to delete the question" that makes perfect sense.  Whenever I have a question that gets a few downvotes, I first bitterly complain to my soup that folks are so so silly they don't understand the question, then I delete the question. (Nobody wants downvoted questions hanging around.)

Comment: @JoeBlow I do keep downvoted question (also now it is +10/-8) - good place for people to use they votes to express significant disagreement with my comments :)

Comment: "it is good enough to keep because others might stumble upon this same bug/feature" Your answer has not been deleted, if it help others in the future, you will get upvotes for it.

Comment: In this case it's probably a matter of OP accepting your answer because it looked right, and then once they got around to it, they were probably unable to implement your suggestion or code successfully, prompting them to conclude "well this doesn't work after all because I can't get it to work". It's *extremely* rare that they would intentionally unaccept a previously-accepted answer for other reasons (such as malice).

Comment: I didn't even know that while we cannot change our votes on a question after some rather short amount of time, we can change the accepted answer any time at will. Wondering what's the motivation for this.

Comment: @5gon The idea is you can upvote as many answers as you want because you found them helpful, but only *one* answer can be accepted as "the most helpful". So if a new answer is posted later that you find *more* helpful, it is perfectly fine to change and accept it instead. But you wouldn't change your vote on the old answer, because it was still helpful. You could upvote the new one *also*. (Note that you can change your vote on an answer if it is edited, because the edit could render it no longer helpful [or helpful when it was not helpful before].)

Comment: nothing you can do and nor should you be able to; other than post on meta and let the meta-effect get you more rep than the 15 you *"lost"*, well played!

Comment: Closing remark (if it's up to me): Thanks all for the response, this meta-question drew more attention than I expected. And indeed @JarrodRoberson I got significant rep from the meta-effect, although that was (honestly!) not my intent. I feel sorry the OP got downvotes, as his question isn't that bad. I learned from Mat that an @ only notifies people that already commented. So I tried to notify the OP (again) and got a response(!). So there is nothing fishy going on, nor is the OP a get-an-answer-run-away-user. A learnfull experience this. Subject closed as far as I am concerned.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> I have already tried to ask the OP for a reason; maybe I can improve something, but there has been no response (for 2 weeks). What else can/should I do?

Move on and answer some other questions. One accept gone will not destroy your future and SE swag. The OP probably unaccepted your answer for some reason or another, but the clear thing is that the OP didn't feel that your answer was the best and deserved the accept. 15 rep isn't that much so just move on with life.

If the OP isn't responding, he/she is clearly not going to change his/her mind anytime soon so don't try asking the OP again. Unfortunately, there is no other way possible to move on. Of course, just flag the question if you're as suspicious as Hans Passant:

> Something fishy is going on, the question was upvoted at the exact same time your answer was unaccepted. Somebody is not using socks to keep his feet warm. You can flag a moderator.

Comment: `[...] the clear thing is that the OP didn't feel that your answer was the best and deserved the accept.` - They might also have mis-clicked, or might not understand exactly what the buttons do.

Comment: Actually:  *"so don't try asking the OP again"*  My question, ***Why not?***  RHA (or anyone who happens to want to) should continually ask the OP about, well anything, as often as they want. OPs are happy enough to use SO, and to get answer(s).  if there's a laissez-faire, "do whatever you want" vibe ("untick an answer if you feel like it") - seems fine to merely ask the OP a few times for what was the untick. Right?  It's not "rude" or anything to ask why they unticked.

Comment: @JoeBlow there is no *value* in asking again - you'd spent time on writing comment/question (and trying to not be complete @#@# at the same time), but OP simply unlikely to answer (I doubt user with 1 rep gets so many comments that one is drowned).  There are more productive questions to spend own time on compared to particular -3 one. It is definitely personal choice, but I'd not spend effort on the question.

Answer (score 5):

Every so often I'll use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/438889/unaccepted-answer-audit?minAnswerScore=1&UserId=621962) to audit my popular answers to questions which don't already have an accepted answer.

[image]

If it looks like the OP was recently active, has asked a few questions, and has accepted some answers, I'll attempt to engage them, e.g.:

> Did you ever get this resolved?

It's *intended* to subtly nudge the OP into re-evaluating the question and its answers or, at the very least, to coax out a little feedback. In my experience, though... it rarely works. Sadly, there's not much to be done about that. It's ultimately up to the OP where that tick goes.

I can't imagine that repeated attempts would help.

Comment: You know, adding a "weeks absent"-column might be a good idea for a quick overview if the asker is likely to *ever* accept it: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/437628/users-positive-score-answers-to-questions-without-an-accepted-answer?UserId=621962

Comment: @Deduplicator absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

Having looked at the OP's profile, it looks like a case of Ask a Question, Get and Answer, Run Away - in other words, an inactive user who's already got what they want and is not likely to come back unless they want to ask another question. Such users, I feel, don't really care about things like reputation, SO is a free source of help for them, nothing more.

Unfortunate, but nothing can be done.

EDIT

Since I wrote my answer above, the OP of the question you answered has since answered a question, so it seems my impression of him/her was wrong.

Comment: But then why did they come back to mark the answer unaccepted?

Comment: I am sorry to say, but your answer was wrong in the first place. Because if he had Run away, he wouldn't have come back after to months to unaccept the answer. And he proved that by in the end, responding. There are a lot of 1-rep users as you describe, but this was not one of them.

Comment: I have encountered this scenario and moved on. OP unaccepted my answer and posted his new answer after 2 months and accepted his own answer, which is inferior to mine.  His answer was down voted by some one else later.